# Reading the first column of a space-delimited text file using stream in java 8

Tags: parsing, java-8, java-stream

My attempt:

```
public class TestStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] uniqueWords = Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/testfile"), Charset.defaultCharset()).flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).limit(1));
        System.out.println(uniqueWords);
    }
}
```

Apparently the `File.lines...` part does not return an String array. How can I make this work?

#### update

Another try:

```
List<String> uniqueWords = Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/testfile"), Charset.defaultCharset()).flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).stream().findFirst()).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(uniqueWords);
```

still no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Finally got it:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
public class TestDosage {
    private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> x = Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/testfile"), Charset.defaultCharset())
            .map(line -> pattern.split(line, 2)[0])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `line -> firstWord(line)` with a method reference, `TestDosage::firstWord`. On the other hand, the code of that method is short enough to fit into a lambda expression, especially after rewriting it using a conditional expression: `line -> { Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line); return m.find()? m.group(): null; }`.

Comment: What is the advantage of using a method reference?

Comment: In most cases, a method reference is more compact, saving you from declaring and referencing lambda parameters. It also creates slightly more compact byte code as it directs the lambda instance right to the target method without creating a synthetic method in your class holding the delegating code.